# How to print the escape characters as it is while using PrettyPrintWriter?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Using PrettyPrintWriter to pretty print the xml file
In the generated xml file the ' (apostrophe) is getting written as &apos
Want it to print as '

Using the following
**xstream.marshal(obj, new PrettyPrintWriter(writer))**  to pretty print
,any suggestions on how to print the escape characters as it is?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own implementation of `PrettyPrintWriter`, which extends that class and overrides its `writeText(QuickWriter, String)` method.

In its most basic form that would be something like this:

```java
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class MyPrettyPrintWriter extends PrettyPrintWriter {

    public MyPrettyPrintWriter(Writer writer) {
        super(writer);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeText(QuickWriter writer, String string) {
        writer.write(string); 
    }
}
```

You would use this as follows:

```java
String s = "Foo'Bar";
XStream xstream = new XStream();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("my_demo.xml");
xstream.marshal(s, new MyPrettyPrintWriter(writer));
```

The output file contains the following:

```
<string>Foo'Bar</string>
```

---

This is basic - it just passes the tag contents through to the file unchanged - nothing is escaped.

You are OK for content containing `"`, `'` and `>`. But this will be a problem for text containing `>` and `&` - which should still be escaped. So you can enhance your `writeText` method to handle those cases as needed. See [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/12567365) for more details.

Note also this is only for text values - not for XML attributes. There is a separate [`writeAttributeValue`](https://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/index.html) method for that (probably not needed in your scenario).

---

It is worth adding: There should be no need to do any of this. The XML is valid, with escaped values such as `&apos;`. Any process (any half-way decent XML library or tool) reading that data should handle them correctly.